# kubectl - list all port forwards across all services?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm new to kubernetes and am wondering if there's a way for me to see a list of all currently configured port forwards using `kubectl` ?

I see there's a `kubectl port-forward` command, but it doesn't seem to list them, just set one up.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{range.spec.ports}}{{if .nodePort}}{{.nodePort}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'
```

Port forwards are listed in the services the above command should loop through all of them and print them out

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58880685/26510) which builds off of Dylans, for how to format this nicely

Comment: On Windows I get this error: ```error: error parsing template {{range .items}}{{range.spec.ports}}{{if .nodePort}}{{.nodePort}}{{\n}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}, template: output:1: unexpected "\\" in command```

Comment: On windows you need to invert the quotes so the argument is double quoted: `kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o go-template="{{range .items}}{{range.spec.ports}}{{if .nodePort}}{{.nodePort}}{{'\n'}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}"`, @user2233706

Answer (score 24):

In addition to Dylan's answer, small adjustment to use with jq.

```
kubectl get svc -o json | jq '.items[] | {name:.metadata.name, p:.spec.ports[] } | select( .p.nodePort != null ) | "\(.name): localhost:\(.p.nodePort) -> \(.p.port) -> \(.p.targetPort)"'
```

```
"web1: localhost:30329 -> 8080 -> 8080"
"web2: localhost:30253 -> 8080 -> 8080"
```

Answer (score 15):

If the question is about listing which ports have been forwarded from a client host to a pod on a Kubernetes cluster...I am not aware of a `kubectl` / `kubectl port-forward` command for that.

Ultimately, a `kubectl port-forward` ends up calling the `/api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods/{name}/portforward` [endpoint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#create-connect-portforward-pod-v1-core) and establishes a connection to one of the Kubernetes [API servers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-apiserver) over the `SPDY` protocol; the kube-apiserver then proxies the connection to a concrete pod. That seems to be the case for when forwarding port(s) with `kubectl port-forward` to a concrete pod, pod selected from a deployment, or pod for a particular Kubernetes service.

Given that the kube-apiserver proxies the connection, examining the network connections on the client or server side with something like `lsof` only shows the port number of the proxy (say, 443 or 8443) for connections to it. On the client side then, using the PID, you can figure out on which port it is listening on - that is the local port that's forwarded.

Also on the client side, just listing all `kubectl` processes using something like `ps -f | grep 'kubectl' | grep 'port-forward'` will list all current port forwards established with `kubectl port-forward`

Answer (score 11):

A modification of Oleg Butuzov answer for all namespaces of your cluster.

```
kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o json | jq '.items[] | {name:.metadata.name, ns:.metadata.namespace, p:.spec.ports[] } | select( .p.nodePort != null ) | "\(.ns)/\(.name): localhost:\(.p.nodePort) -> \(.p.port) -> \(.p.targetPort)"'
# output
"dbtest/mysql: localhost:31281 -> 3306 -> mysql"
```

Answer (score 7):

If the question is about the port forwards established from the client to the cluster, this will do:

```
ps -f | grep 'kubectl' | grep 'port-forward' | awk '{print $10 " " $11}'
```